# Good names for \, and \! with nonempty glues

Tags: spacing, white-space, horizontal, glue

Let's assume that you often wish to insert a stretchable thin space instead of a fixed-size`\,`.  Your document is full of `\mskip3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu` in math mode or `\hskip.16667em plus.08333333em minus.08333333em` in text mode.  What would be a good short name that doesn't clash with anything instead of `\thinGlueSkip` in

```
\newcommand{\thinGlueSkip}{\ifmmode\mskip3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu\else\hskip.16667em plus.08333em minus.08333em\fi}
```

?  This is supposed to act equally to `\,`, except it stretches and shrinks a bit when necessary. Is there, perhaps, already a name for this (or, more generally, for `\,` with some glue) already in some standard LaTeX package?

Similary, how about naming `\negThinGlueSkip` in

```
\newcommand{\negThinGlueSkip}{\ifmmode\mskip-3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu\else\hskip-.16667em plus.08333em minus.08333em\fi}
```

shorter? More generally, is there already a somewhat standard name for `\!` with a nonzero glue?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you give one or two examples where you feel the need to insert these spaces?

Comment: are you sure you don't simply want to give `\thinmuskip` some stretch so all thin skips are consistent?

Comment: @mickep When you write a long in-line formula such as `a\!+\!b=c \,\land\, d\!+\!e=f \,\land\,…` and wish that the structure of the formula gets more vivid.

Comment: i suspect the question in the title meets the standard "opinion based" close reason.

Comment: eek why would you _ever_ write `a\!+\!b=c \,\land\, d\!+\!e=f` ? Just set medmuskip don't space _every indvidual_ operator!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Giving `\thinmuskup` a different meaning might break too many other unrelated things, I'm afraid. As for spacing individual operators: we need, e.g., different spacings around the relations `=` and `\land`. By default, they are both `\mathrel`s with equal spacing, aren't they?

Comment: so define `\thickmuskip` for = and define  `\land` to adjust its space no need for `\,\land\,` in the document

Comment: @micrep … and you wish that your long in-line formula stretches and shrinks with the remainder of the containing paragraph.

Comment: @GeekestGeek it doesn't have to be global it can be a local setting like `\boldmath`  so `{\stretchymath $a+b=c$}`  with`\def\stretchymath{\thinmuskip=3mu plus 2mu minus 1mu \medmuskip...}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sometimes we typeset stuff such as `Consider the formula \(F\ \,=\ \,\bigl((\forall\ a\!\in\! X, b\!\in\! Y, c\!\in\! C\colon a\!+\!b=c \,\land\, d\!+\!e=f \,\land\,…) \>\land\> (…)\bigr)\)`. In this example, the innermost usages of `=` and `\land` would profit from “standard” glue `\mskip3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu`, whereas the outer `\land` and the outermost `=` would profit from more glue. So, while `\mskip3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu` and `\mskip-3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu` is our typical usage, it's by no means unique even within a formula for a symbol.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps, `\mskip3mu plus1.5mu minus1.5mu` is standard only to many parts of many formulas, but not more than that. In text mode, we use `\hskip.16667em plus.08333em minus.08333em` when typesetting formulas in computer programs as partially text (say, we typeset the sort of a variable `b` and its initialization as `b\(\colon\) \textbf{var} \,\textsf{Seq}\,\textsf{Bit} = some sequence`).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My hope is that someone in some package has already given a name for `\,`-with-appropriate-glue and I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: People who need square wheels have to build them themselves:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't see why you think my usage would be a square wheel. In fact, a need to stretch and shrink inline formulas with boolean junctors and `=` on various levels occurs naturally when you typeset papers/books on logics and computer science.

Comment: not so much the desired output as the desired input: if you are typing `\somcommand+\somcommand`  my only suggested name is `\DontDoThis` I can't think of a name you'd actually give me a green tick for....

Comment: Well, what would be an appropriate™ way to endow certain occurrences of the addition symbol `+` with smaller spacing, say, `\mskip2mu plus1mu minus1mu\mathord{+}\mskip2mu plus1mu minus1mu` instead of the IMHO standard `\mskip5mu plus5mu\mathord{+}\mskip5mu plus 5mu`? For some usages, of course; not globally.

Comment: set medmuskip (locally within subformulas if needed, just as `\boldsymbol` is a nested version of `\boldmath`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't recall ever using `\boldsymbol` or `\boldmath`, let alone going into their implementation (e.g., I see that amsbsy.sty defines `\boldsymbol`, but not through `\boldmath`).  Anyway, you may have various levels inside a formula and decide to typeset some binary operators with less spacing and some with more. E.g., you might wish to make the structure of the formula “a·b+c·d” more vivid by having less space around the dot: `a\mskip2mu plus1mu minus1mu\mathord{\cdotp}\mskip2mu plus1mu minus1mu b + c\mskip2mu plus1mu minus1mu\mathord{\cdotp}\mskip2mu plus1mu minus1mu d`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138696/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-geekestgeek).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle However, setting `\medmuskip` would change the spacing around both · and +, wouldn't it?

Comment: amsmath provides `\\*` starred version of line break `\\­` that prohibits the page break, so similarly, I would redefine existing `\,` and `\!` to be stretchable and define unstretchable  starred versions `\,*` and `\!*`

Comment: @antshar Better the converse